# Netbeans - Como gerar um jar com dependências sem o Maven

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Tenho um projeto no Netbeans, porém eu só conheço o Maven e tenho algumas dependências no projeto.

Se der build ou até mesmo rodar no Netbeans tudo funciona tranquilamente, porém eu queria pegar o `jar` e testar em outras máquinas.

Tentei exportar o `jar` mas dá erro de `ClassNotFound`.

Como posso fazer isso? Qual é a maneira correta?

Comment: Pode incluir a mensagem completa do erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionalmente, você pode adicionar os jars dependentes usando o método tradicional:

```
File > Project Properties > Libraries > Run-Time Libraries
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode empacotar as dependências no jar usando Maven. O site da Netbeans, inclusive, tem o passo-a-passo:

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html

Comment: exatamente isso que eu não queria.

Comment: Bom, veja se a outra resposta te ajuda.